# How do I add UFW rules and a comment/name?

Tags: ufw

How do I open a port range, for example: xxxx-xxxx and name it something so when I get back I in a month or whatever and look at my UFW config I know what those ports are for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution that I found:

Use your favorite text editor and make a file at: `/etc/ufw/applications.d/foo` where foo is just a variable name for your service.

In this text file you add:

```
[foo]
title=A title
description=A description
ports=xxx/tcp|xxx/udp|xxxx:xxxx/udp
```

Note that it if 'foo' that will show up in the ufw list.

Then update the ufw `sudo ufw app update foo` and open the ports for that service with: `sudo ufw allow foo`

Answer (score 0):

There's a "comment" parameter to add rule comments as described here:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-adding-comments-to-ufw-firewall-rule/

If you "create" a rule which is exactly the same as an existing with an additional comment to it, it will update the rule.

The basics.

```
ufw {rule-here} comment '{comment-text-here}'
```

Example.

```
sudo ufw allow from 178.192.0.0/13 to 172.16.0.1 port ssh proto tcp comment "Allow SSH from Swisscom (Schweiz) AG"
```

Output looks something like this.

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
172.16.0.1 22/tcp          ALLOW       178.192.0.0/13             # Allow SSH from Swisscom (Schweiz) AG
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/453393)